# Main and objects,Java

Tags: java, object, constructor

I have a noob questions,s orry for wasting your time but could somebody explain?

```
public class Ex {
    public  int a = 0;
    public Ex(int x){
            a = x;
        int y = 10;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Ex obj = new Ex(10);
        System.out.println(Ex.a);   
    }
}
```

Why isn't this working? I tried to put constructor in main but that ain't working either.

Comment: Without static,i forgot to mention

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires an introduction into how types work. This is way too broad for Stack Overflow and you should instead read a tutorial or a book.

Comment: `Without static` ? Yes, you might want to mention that, cause it's the main cause making your program to fail.

Comment: Explain what? You haven't said what happens or what you expected to happen. Likewise "that ain't working" doesn't tell us anything about what you observed. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(obj.a);
```

Ex.a you can use if your attribute is static, but a is not static

Answer (score 0):

Your object is called `obj`, and `a` belongs to your object, not to your class.

```
System.out.println(obj.a);
```

`Ex.a` would work if `a` was a static class member.